# Is @ContextHierarchy useful out of the inheritance scenario?

Tags: java, spring, junit4, spring-test

I mean, if I annotate unrelated classes with it, will Spring infer the logical hierarchy or is it a mechanism only suitable for physical hierarchies (abstract class and child, like the examples of the Spring documentation)

What I am after is a way to tell the context cache to reuse certain configuration classes used by different test classes which don´t conform a suite (i.e, have the same context confiuration identity http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching)

Comment: Just a friendly note that if you find one of the answers to your question acceptable, feel free to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I annotate unrelated classes with it, will Spring infer the logical hierarchy

No, `@ContextHierarchy` does not magically *infer* anything from classes it doesn't know about.

As demonstrated in the Spring Framework reference manual, there are two basic scenarios for using `@ContextHierarchy`.

1. For creating a context hierarchy within a single test class. (see `ControllerIntegrationTests` in the reference manual)
2. For creating a context hierarchy within a test class hierarchy. (see `SoapWebServiceTests` in the reference manual)

> What I am after is a way to tell the context cache to reuse certain configuration classes used by different test classes which don´t conform a suite

As long as the configuration for those different test classes results in the exact same *context cache key* (see the Spring reference manual), then that already works. That's in fact one of the main benefits of the Spring TestContext Framework.

If you mean something else, then I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Hi Sam! Thank you for your answer. So ContextHierarchy does not have use for what I tried to acomplish. What I want is precisely to indicate that certain contexts be reused even though the context key is different on each class

Comment: By the way, if mocking certain beans in the `ApplicationContext` would help solve your issues, you should take a loot at Spring Boot 1.4's `@MockBean` support.